# Check if string contains three same letters in Octave

Tags: string, matlab, octave

I'm trying to make a function in Octave to check whether a string contains three consecutive same characters. That is, if my string is `"asdf"` it should return `0` and if it's like `"asdfffg"` it should return 1. What I did so far is this

```
if(length(findstr(word,"aaa",0)) > 1 || length(findstr(word,"bbb",0)) > 1 ||   ..
```

It's costly and I think not that really inefficient. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a **regular expression**:

```
match = regexp(word, '(.)\1{2}', 'once');
```

This means: match any character (`(.)`), followed by that same character (`\1`) twice (`{2}`). It will return the starting index of the first match, or an empty array if there isn't any match. So your desired result would be

```
result = ~isempty(match);
```

---

Another possibility is to use **convolution**:

```
result = any(conv([1 1], +~diff(word))==2);
```

This works as follows: `diff` will give `0` when two consecutive characters are the same. So you want to detect if the output of `diff` contains two consecutive zeros. This is done by negating (`~`), converting to `double` (`+`), convolving with the sequence `[1 1]` (`conv([1 1], ...)`), and seeing if `2` is present in the output.

Comment: Loving the golf tricks in the second answer. I personally prefer [`llhjd~X+2=a`](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=bGxoamR-WCsyPWE&input=YWFhYWJiYw) :)

Comment: @Suever Or `TTjd~X+2=a`, maybe? :-P

Comment: I had no idea that T/F values concatenated like that. Noted!